# regex: How to match escaped double quoted strings?

Tags: php, python, ruby, regex

I have strings such as the following:

```
\"Some text inside here. And perhaps special chars including newlines...\" then more text (out here)
```

**How do I simply match and return that which is in between the escaped double quotes, discarding the rest?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that there are only two escaped double quotes in the string

```
match = s.match(/\\"(.*)\\"/m)
match[1] if match
```

Comment: Even if you assume only one pair of quotes (why?), it will not work if there are newlines in between (as requested by the OP).

Comment: The simply make it matching newlines `/m`. Changed the answer.

Comment: `m` is the multiline switch, it makes `^` match the start of the line and `$` the end of the line, I assume you meant `s` it makes the dot matches newline characters.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use this pattern:

```
    \".*\"
```

since "dot" does not match the new-line character unless you use the flag 's' which makes the "dot" match everything (including new-line character)

and even more this pattern would mismatch this example:

```
    "this is a quoted text" and "this is another one"
```

the pattern above would match the whole string instead of the two quoted texts. (since .* is greedy and would match the longest string it can, in this case the whole string.) instead you should use .*? which makes the pattern "reluctant" and it would match the shortest string it can.

so to wrap it up you can use this pattern with flag "s" (dot-match-all):

```
    \".*?\"
```

or use this:

```
    \"[^"]\"
```

which doesn't require the "s" flag. (since [^"] matches anything but " which includes new-line.)

(I'm not familiar with PHP syntax, so you should take care of applying the flags and escaping the characters yourself.)

Comment: +1, thats an answer with a good explanation, two points: 1. if you want to match the backslash you need to escape it in the pattern, 2. your example with the negated char class will fail if there are unescaped quotes between the escaped ones. And alternative is the lazy quantifier together with the `s` modifier something like `\\".*?\\"`

Comment: @Sahand: But it's easier to turn on multi-line matching mode for "." (see the other answer)

Comment: by turning on multi-line flag you make $ and ^ match start and end of line. it doesn't make dot match new-line.
(as I mentioned, the syntax defers between languages and I'm not familiar with PHP's. So I left escaping and etc to the reader.)

Answer (score 1):

This should works fine for you:

```
b'\\".*?\\"'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without regex too:

```
$str = '\"Some text inside here. And perhaps special chars including newlines...\" then more text (out here)';

$out = explode('"', $str);

echo $out[0]; // outputs "\"
echo $out[1]; // outputs "Some text... ...\"
echo $out[2]; // outputs " then...here)"
```